# The thing a person with a one-track mind is stuck on

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

T. has a one-track mind.  He is a school psychologist who thinks that the solution to all teenage special learners' problems is for the teen to attend all his planning meetings with school personnel.  He is so stuck on this idea that he can't even recognize when the parents are already allowing and encouraging the teen to take an active role in the family's advocacy efforts.

What can I call the thing the one-track-minded person is stuck on?  It's an *idée fixe* but I often have to communicate with people who are unlikely to understand *idée fixe*.  I end up calling it T.'s *thing*.  Strictly speaking it is an *obsession* but this give offense.

Example sentence:

> T.'s _________ is that teens should attend their own meetings and advocate for themselves.

I don't mind recasting if it helps me communicate with an unsophisticated audience.

**Edit:** I think Lee Leon cracked it:

> T. feels it's his **mission** to get teens to attend their own meetings and advocate for themselves.

Comment: ***Fixation***. Or *obsession* or other synonyms you can find in a thesaurus starting here.

Comment: @DanBron - *Thing* has a more neutral tone than *fixation*.  Granted, *fixation* is a bit more neutral in tone than *obsession*, but I'd prefer something as neutral as *thing*.

Comment: Then try ***focus***, ***objective***, ***aim***, and so forth.

Comment: @DanBron - Thanks for the suggestions, but for me, those don't imply one-track-mindedness.  Do they for you?

Comment: *Focus* does. Even in its imagery.

Comment: @DanBron - My son has ADHD.  I hear constant complaints from his teachers about his difficulty maintaining his focus.  *Focus* cannot be assumed to be remotely equivalent to *obsession*.  There would have to be careful context built up for it to be taken this way.

Comment: Either you want the absolute sense of *fixation* or *obsession* and the attendant connotations (which will inevitably have both positive and negative lenses), or you want the neutrality of your "thing-like" word, similar to *focus* or *objective* (with its attendant weakness relative to *obsession*). Anything with the absolute sense of *obsession* will necessarily have been applied pejoratively historically, and therefore have developed at least one negative sense. I don't think you can have your cake and eat it too.  But I've been wrong before, and I won't be surprised if I'm wrong again.

Comment: @DanBron - "Thing" gives me both.  If possible I'd like to find an alternative to "thing."  "Thing" has so many meanings.  And it feels like a bit of a cop-out.  However, the answer to my question might be that "thing" is the unique happy medium word.

Comment: I personally don’t think “thing” gives you both. It’s weak, generic, and doesn’t have the “single track mindedness” you question asks for. A “thing” can be a minor interest, a quirk of the personality, etc.

Comment: @DanBron - "Thing" works in my sentence -- but I agree it's not ideal, that was my point exactly.  See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thing Definition 7b, "a mild obsession or phobia."

Comment: You could try **bugbear** - a cause of obsessive fear, anxiety, or irritation.

Comment: @LeeLeon - thanks, getting closer.  But I think *bugaboo* and *bugbear* are probably about negative minor obsessions, and I want a positive minor obsession, as in *idée fixe*.  Like when a researcher feels driven, and ends up with a major discovery.

Comment: How about **quest** or **mission**? Using the word 'sole' beforehand would make it more one-track, single-minded.

Comment: @LeeLeon - Thanks, if you write an answer I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest [**quest**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quest) or [**mission**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mission). if you want to make it one-track try something like:

> T.'s **sole mission** is that teens should attend their own meetings and advocate for themselves.